# VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object! Cannot handle settings version '1.2-macosx'

Tags: macos, kubernetes

Unable to start VM: create: precreate: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage list hostonlyifs failed:
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage: error: Error in /Users//Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml (line 3) -- Cannot handle settings version '1.2-macosx'.
VBoxManage: error: /Users/vbox/tinderbox/6.0-mac-rel/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[624] (nsresult VirtualBox::init())
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox

Comment: It's great that you solved this, but a question consisting of just a big paragraph of error message won't be useful to others (and wouldn't attract an answer if you hadn't found one).  Can you add some context and details?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the VirtualBox.xml file.
   e.g. /Users//Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml

```
$> vi /Users/rmanan/Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml
```

2. Change this value from 1.2-macosx to 1.3-macosx

```
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.2-macosx">
```

3. Start minikube

```
$> minikube start
```